# Plotting GP 95% confidence intervals in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, confidence-interval, gaussian-process

I used Gaussian Process regression to fit my data and it works very well. However, when I am trying to plot the confidence intervals on my estimation. I am getting a messy Graph see below.

[image]

The red line represents upper CI while the blue line represents lower CI and the black line is my estimated data. I have written following code for this

```
f3 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(X_te_rescale[:,0],pred_y.ravel(),'k.',markersize=20,label='prediction')
plt.plot(X_te_rescale[:,0],low_CIs,'b.',markersize=2)
plt.plot(X_te_rescale[:,0],Upper_CIs,'r.',markersize=2)
plt.legend(loc='1')
plt.show()
```

I searched in google and found `fill between` can be useful for this and hence used it also and result also is bad. see graph below

[image]

Main GP code

```
pred_y, sigma = gpr.predict(X_te_rescale, return_std=True)
confidence_interval = sigma * 1.96
low_CIs=pred_y - confidence_interval
Upper_CIs= pred_y + confidence_interval
```

The code, I wrote for this are as follows

```
plt.scatter(X_tr_rescale, y_tr_rescale, label='Train data')
plt.fill_between(X_te_rescale[:,0],
                  pred_y[:,0] - confidence_interval,
                  pred_y[:,0] + confidence_interval,
                  facecolor='black', alpha=0.5, label='95% confidence interval')
plt.gca().set_title(gp.kernel_)
plt.plot(X_te_rescale, pred_y, 'r.',label='Prediction')
```

Details of data are as follows.

```
y_te_rescale: Array of floats64 (1188,1)
sigma: Array of floats64 (1188,)
Confidence interval: Array of floats64 (1188,)
lower CIs: Array of floats64 (1188,1188)
upper CIs: Array of floats64 (1188,1188)
pred_y: Array of floats64 (1188,1)
```

Is it possible to have a CI that does not overlap my estimated values? Or something I am missing. Thanks in advance.
Based on the comments I modified the code as below

```
x_unsorted=X_te_rescale.flatten()
pred_y=pred_y.flatten()
sorted_inds = np.argsort(x_unsorted)
plt.fill_between(
    x_unsorted[sorted_inds],
    (pred_y - confidence_interval)[sorted_inds],
    (pred_y+ confidence_interval)[sorted_inds],
    label='95% CI',
)
plt.plot(
    x_unsorted[sorted_inds], 
    pred_y.ravel[sorted_inds], 
    'r--',
    label='Prediction',
)
```

This gives graph as below

[image]

The above code though show confidence interval but not able to estimated value. Is this code is correct ? or how to plot confidence intervals together with an estimated value which can clearly be seen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your use of `plt.fill_between` is that the x values are not sorted. `plt.plot` would produce a similarly bad result if you were plotting a line instead of a set of points.

Try something like this:

```py
sorted_inds = np.argsort(x_unsorted)
plt.fill_between(
    x_unsorted[sorted_inds],
    (y_pred - conf_intervals)[sorted_inds],
    (y_pred + conf_intervals)[sorted_inds],
    label='95% CI',
)
plt.plot(
    x_unsorted[sorted_inds], 
    y_pred[sorted_inds], 
    'k-',
    label='Prediction',
)
```

Comment: I have modified the code with yours but getting an error 'Input passed into argument "'x'"is not 1-dimensional.' Any idea why. Please see the code that modified as per your code.

Comment: @ravipandit I assume you're hitting this error on the call to `fill_between`. This is because matplotlib treats row vectors differently from 1D arrays. If your `x` has shape `(N, 1)`, passing `x.flatten()` instead of `x` should solve the problem.

Comment: I took your suggestion and modified accordingly. The code though shows confidence interval but not able to estimated value. How to plot confidence intervals together with an estimated value which can clearly be seen.

Comment: @ravipandit have you checked your code for syntax errors? It looks like there's a mistake in your call to `plt.plot`.

Comment: I found an error  when running this ''builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable'. I tried myself to sort this but did not found any solution for this.

Comment: @ravipandit that would be from the error I mentioned in your call to `plt.plot`. Note that if `foo` is a function, `foo()[0]` will get you the first item in a vector returned by the function, but `foo[0]` will produce the error you're getting. I suggest going through your call to `plt.plot` line by line to check for errors. Try to understand what each line does, and whether it's necessary.